# Use a other Method in a static method

Tags: c#, timer, elapsed

How can I use the method `ChangeText` in my static method `timer_Elapsed`?

```
public Load()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;

    // I can't transfer parameters here
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed); 
    timer.Start();
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Its underlined in red. I need a object reference?
    ChangeText(); 
}

public void ChangeText()
{
    label1.Text = label1.Text + ".";
}
```

Comment: Remove static on your timer_Elapsed method ?

Comment: Why is timer_Elapsed static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As first, your method (timer_Elapsed) could not me static, in order to use an instance property (label1)

There is an other problem in your code: Timer create an other thread, an most of windows control properties can be modified only by UI thread. Your code will throw a CrossThreadException.
In order to resolve your problem , you should modify your code with this:

```
if(this.InvokeRequired) {
   BeginInvoke(
       new MethodInvoker(delegate { label.Text+="."; }));
} else {
    label.Text+="."; 
}
```

Regards

Comment: Ooh, good spot - an easier fix for this, though, would be to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (since the example looks like winforms), which would call back on the correct thread automatically

Comment: ty for this! (it was an InvalidOperationException)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason why `timer_Elapsed` should be `static`. So simply remove it.

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeText(); //Its not underlined anymore, you have an object reference
}
```

Another way would be to make `ChangeText` static.  But that won't work since you want to set a `Label`'s Text, so you need an instance of the `Form` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Make ChangeText a static method.

```
public static void ChangeText()
```

Comment: ChangeText clearly talks to instance state; the better solution is to make the `timer_Elapsed` method non-static

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call instance methods in static ones without creating an instance first. You have to create an instance of the class this method belongs to. like below:

```
var instance = new Load();
instance.ChangeText();
```

*Update:*
As other answers suggested, you should reconsider defining `timer_Elapsed` as static.

Comment: since the timer is started by the `Load` constructor, this would be a very bad idea; how many do you want?

Comment: @MarcGravell I know this is not a good idea. Just simply answered OP's question and updated my answer with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Only static methods are called from a static method,
Either make your `ChangeText()` method to static or make your `time_Elapsed` method to non-static

Comment: the ElapsedEventHandler need a static method so i cant change it. The text from a label is changed in the ChangeText method, when i make it to static i cant access to the label

Answer (score 1):

Hi Can you try like below:

```
public Load()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;

    // I can't transfer parameters here
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed); 
    timer.Start();
}
 private delegate void ChangeLabel();
        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ChangeLabel = new ChangeLabel(ChangeText);
            this.BeginInvoke(ChangeLabel);

        }
        private void ChangeText()
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text + ".";
        }
```